# Twilio PHP SDK, make outbound call, receive DTMF input from user and redirect call

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

I'm trying to make an outbound call from Twilio using Twilio PHP SDK. But I'm unable to figure out how to fetch DTMF input from that call and then perform some action based on that input e.g. connect the called number to another number if pressed 1.

Here is my code for outbound call:

```
$call = $client->calls->create(
        $phone, "+1xxxx",
        array(
            "url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
            "method" => "GET",
            "statusCallbackMethod" => "POST",
            "statusCallback" => "http://xxxx.com/twilio/call_xxx",
            "statusCallbackEvent" => array(
                "answered"
            )
        )
    );
```

And code for handling webhook request:

```
    //Use the Twilio PHP SDK to build an XML response
    $response = new Twiml();

    //If the user entered digits, process their request
    if(array_key_exists('Digits', $_POST)) {
        switch ($_POST['Digits']) {
            case 1:
                $dial = $response->dial();
                $dial->number($phone);
                break;
            default:
                $response->say('Goodbye.');
        }
    } else {

        //If no input was sent, use the <Gather> verb to collect user input
        $gather = $response->gather(array('numDigits' => 1));

        // use the <Say> verb to request input from the user
        $gather->say("This is xxx. $name just requested a voucher. Press 1 to connect with them now.");

        // If the user doesn't enter input, loop
        $response->redirect('/twilio/call_xxxx');
    }

    //Render the response as XML in reply to the webhook request
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    echo $response;
```

Where am I making mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a mistake here, based on your code this:

```
"url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
"method" => "GET",
```

should really be:

---

```
"url" => "http://xxxx.com/twilio/call_xxx",
"method" => "POST",
```

---

to fetch the TwiML for the call flow and also pass the `Digits` you are looking for.

As for `statusCallback`, if you need it, you'll have to create another endpoint with different code (has to do with tracking the status of the call).

I would suggest, get it working without statusCallback first (you can remove the statusCallback... lines temporarily ).